# Delete all duplicated charcters from strings - c

Tags: c, string, function

I am trying to delete all duplicate characters from a given string.
For example "asdasd" = "asd" or "abbgga" = "abg".

When I compile and when cmd starts to run it I am getting "stopped working" message.

This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void delMul(char str[]){
    int i,j=0;
    int s[26];
    char k ;
    for ( i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        s[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        k = str[i] - 'a'; 
        if(s[k] == 0) {
            s[k]++ ;
            str[j++] = str[i];
        }
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
}

int main(){
    char *str = "asdasd";
    delMul(str);
    puts(str);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug this?

Comment: Change `char *str = "asdasd";` to `char str[] = "asdasd";` as in the first case `str` is a string literal stored in read only memory.

Comment: first problem:  there are 256 characters not just 26 and need to allow for all those characters.   Second problem: the array "asdasd"  is a string literal,  and string literals are in readonly memory, so this statement: `str[j++] = str[i];`  will result in a seg fault event.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)   Then fix the warnings, so the code cleanly compiles.   You could start with the variable 'k' needs to be a 'int', not a 'char'

Comment: the posted code, even after suggested fixes, will fail with a string like: "hello   World!"  as the posted code does not handle capital letters nor punctuation nor spaces.

Comment: the system function: `strlen()` returns a 'size_t' which is unsigned.  However, 'i' is a 'int'   Suggest changing `int i;` to `size_t i;`   the function `strlen();` is an expensive operation.  suggest only call it once and save the result to use in the 'for' loop

Comment: @oprezyzer Try this: http://ideone.com/qQFl1M

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `str` points to a *string literal*, which might not be modified. Try using an array for the same initialized by the string.

Answer (score 1):

In main you have declared str as a pointer to a string

So the storage is allocated as a fixed string in the program and not as data

So when you attempt to write to it at line 18 `str[j++]=str[i]` there is a
SEGV as this is not allowed

To correct this declare the string as an array of char that is initialized instead

```
int main(){
    char str[] = "asdasd";
    delMul(str);
    puts(str);
}
```