# Finding duplicate numbers and print out the most duplicated first and the rest

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

so far I have managed to find the duplicate numbers but i want to read in the inputs and determine if the there is any duplicated element in the list. If all values are unique print out "list has no duplicate values", otherwise print out the values that are duplicated as they appear from left to right in the list (each separated by a newline character).

I need to print out the most duplicated number in the list followed by the second most duplicate value. How do I do this? I know I have to edit the if statement but I am not sure how.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define size 50

int main(void)
{       
   int i, j, n, du, dup[size];
   bool copy = false;

   scanf("%d", &n);

   for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
      scanf("%d", &dup[i]);
   }

   for (i=0; i<n; i++) {     
      for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
         if (dup[i] == dup[j] && j!=i) {
            copy = true;
         }
      }
   }

   if (copy) {
      printf("list has duplicate values");
   }
   else {
      printf("list has no duplicate values");
   }
   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It must be duplicated characters in strings 101 class time.  Just answered this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994040/delete-all-duplicated-charcters-from-strings-c/32994915#32994915

Comment: Better to change `for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
         if (dup[i] == dup[j] && j!=i) {
            copy = true;
         }
      }` to `for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
         if (dup[i] == dup[j]) {
            copy = true; break;
         }
      }`

Comment: If the input in `1 3 3 3 4 4` 1) Should `3` be printed 1 2 or 3 times? 2) must the order be maintained or would `4 3` be OK?

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the replies. If the input is 133344 example the output should print 3 first then 4. Both only prints once.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define size 50

int intsort(int* val1,int *val2){
    return (*val1<*val2)?-1:(*val1>*val2)?1:0;
}

int main(void)
{       
   int i, j, n, du, dup[size];
   bool copy = false;

   printf("number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n<2) n=2;
    if(n>50) n=50;


    printf("enter elements:\n");

   for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
      printf("\t%d) ",i+1);
      scanf("%d", &dup[i]);
   }


    j=0;i=0;
   qsort(dup,n,sizeof(int),intsort);


    printf("\n=========\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf(" %d",dup[i]);
    printf("\n=========\n");

    i=0;
    while(i<(n-1)){

        for(j=i+1;dup[i]==dup[j];j++);
        copy=(i+1)<j;
        if(copy){

            printf("there are %d copies of %d \n",(j-i),dup[i]);
        }
        i=j;
    }
    if(!copy){
        printf("No duplicated items \n");
    }
    printf("Done\n");


   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define size 50

typedef struct{
    int value,dup;
}LIST_ENTRY;


/*______________________________________________________________
*/
int CompareEntries(LIST_ENTRY* val1,LIST_ENTRY *val2){
        return (val1->dup>val2->dup)?-1:(val1->dup<val2->dup)?1:0;
}
/*______________________________________________________________
*/
int AddEntry(LIST_ENTRY * Entries,int val){
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(Entries[i].value==val){
            Entries[i].dup++;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(Entries[i].dup==0){
            Entries[i].value=val;
            Entries[i].dup++;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
/*______________________________________________________________
*/
void ClearEntries(LIST_ENTRY * Entries){
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        Entries[i].value=0;
        Entries[i].dup=0;
    }
}
/*______________________________________________________________
*/
int main(void)
{       
    int i, d,n;
    bool copy = false;
    LIST_ENTRY Entries[size];

    ClearEntries(Entries);


   printf("number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n<2) n=2;
    if(n>50) n=50;


    printf("enter elements:\n");

   for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
      printf("\t%d) ",i+1);
      scanf("%d", &d);
      copy|=AddEntry(Entries,d);
   }



   qsort(Entries,n,sizeof(LIST_ENTRY),CompareEntries);


    printf("\n=========\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if(Entries[i].dup){
            printf("there are %d copies of %d\n",Entries[i].dup,Entries[i].value);
        }
    }
    printf("\n=========\n");


    if(!copy){
        printf("No duplicated items \n");
    }
    printf("Done\n");


   return 0;
}
```